# Equality with nested cubic radicals. Where is my error?

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

We have

$$\sqrt[3]{ \frac{1 - 3 \sqrt[3]{3}}{11- 3 \sqrt[3]{3}}} = \frac{1 - \sqrt[3]{3}}{2- \sqrt[3]{3}}$$

since

$$\require{cancel}
\sqrt[3]{ \frac{\ 1 -  3^{1/3} 3}{11 - 3^{1/3} 3} }=\frac{(\ 1 -  3^{1/3}\ 3)^{1/3} }{(11 - 3^{1/3}\ 3)^{1/3}}= \frac{(\ 1 -  3^{1/3}\cancel{3})^{1/\cancel{3}} }{(\textrm{II} - 3^{1/3}\bcancel{3})^{1/\bcancel{3}}}= \frac{1 -  3^{1/3}}{2 -  3^{1/3}}
$$

I was told that the above proof is wrong. However, it does check [numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B%7BCubeRoot%5B%281-+3%5E%281%2F3%29+3%29%2F%2811+-+3%5E%281%2F3%29+3%29%5D%2C+%281-3%5E%281%2F3%29%29%2F%282-+3%5E%281%2F3%29%29%7D%2C+13%5D),  both sides equal $-0.7929165927333\ldots$.  Where is my error?

Comment: If there ever was a "*question not about math as we know it*"... ;-)

Comment: I think my computer clock is slow by about $25/4$ days.

Comment: Seems legit! Now where is the MathSX laugh emoji?

Comment: Hint: Your $11$ was written as the roman number two ("$II$").

Comment: the question is off; not by a mile, but by a week :-)